# How to display TABLE dynamically in JSP using SPRING MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to create a table dynamically in such a way that no of headers and data i can pass from JAVA class and on no. basis, jsp should create a table accordingly.

I have controller class in which i am returning model object which is my bean class. In that i have a list attribute in which i have hardcoded some values.These values should be by header names in the JSP table.
When i am rendering this model object to jsp then i am not able to retrieve the headers info. Plz suggest.
My contrller class loooks like this:

```
@RequestMapping
public ModelAndView getHeaders(PortletRequest portlestRequest, PortletResponse portletResponse){

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

    TableDAO dao = new TableDAO();
    List<String> headersList = dao.getHeaders();

    TableView tableView  = new TableView();

    tableView.setTableHeaders(headersList);
    mv.addObject("tableView",tableView);
    mv.setView("tableView");
    return mv;
}
```

My jsp:

```
<table>
<c:forEach var = "listValue" items = "${tableView.tableHeaders}">
    <tr>
      <%for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){ %>
                <td>
                    <%=${listValue.get(i)} %>
                </td>
            <%} %>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Someone plz help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you looking over the list of headers twice? You dont need that scriptlet code.

Since tableView.tableHeaders returns a list of strings, you just need :

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <c:forEach var = "listValue" items = "${tableView.tableHeaders}">
            <td>
                <c:out value="${listValue}"/>
            </td>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it worked.i ned 2 display data blow dese headers.I hav a clas People n in dat i have 2 att. name, age.I created n aray list of PEOPLE. Im doig lik this:        People people1 = new People();people1.setName("abc");people1.setDOB("3-apr-1987");                                            Then:People people2 = new People();people1.setName("xyz");                                                 people1.setDOB("3-dec-1987");then i am setting these two objects in a list n pasing dis lst to d main clas which wilreturned as Model 2 d jsp bt i am geting wrong output. Could u plz sugest how 2 do this.

Comment: comments arent the place for adding another question. Since this question is answered, its best to post a new question if you have a new issue.